# The simplest and most effective way of creating a character that follows the player in Cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

All of the methods that I've seen for getting a camera to follow a player in Cocos2d have been either convoluted or not usable.  Is there a simpler way to just make a camera that is centered on the player for a TDS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way I know is to use CCFollow. Put it in your init method after you declare your sprite.

```
[self runAction:[CCFollow actionWithTarget:aSprite]];
```

or set a world boundary if you have a boundary set.

```
[self runAction:[CCFollow actionWithTarget:aSprite worldBoundary:CGRectMake(0, 0, world_width, world_height)]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to have your character in the centre of the screen whilst walking around your world? If so just do this:

Make your world a TMX map or whatever you wish to use, and add your character as a child of that world.

If the user wishes to walk north, then move the character UP whilst moving the world DOWN with the same speed.

Do the same for every other direction.